# Hosted IronPython resume after accessing non-existing method or property?

Tags: ironpython

Is there a way to make a hosted IronPython engine resume execution of a script after accessing a non-existing method or property of an object instance? Usually an exception is thrown that unfortunately interrupts execution of the script.

I execute IronPython scripts with instances of several different C# classes (e.g. class A and B) in their scopes that implement more or less the same methods and properties. However class A implements more methods and properties in addition to those shared by both classes.

Class A may and should remain throwning the exception as the methods of this class that the script accesses must exist. If they don't there's indeed something wrong with the script.

Class B however is **only** or **visualization** purposes and hence IronPython could ignore/skip calls to methods that don't exist in this class but in class A and continue execution.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inheriting class B from DynamicObject, using *dynamic* as parameter type for the method that runs the script and doing this in the class B

```
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        base.TryInvoke(binder, args, out result);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
        return true;
    }
```

I could achieve what I was asking for. Every call to a non-existing method or property is ignored this way. No matter what source the call comes from. Calls to existing methods/properties however work as usual.